# Update a particular JSON field using Sequelize in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a "user" table with one of the fields "info" being a JSON structure:

user table has these fields: id, name, info, created

info filed has this structure:

info: {
  email,
  password,
  device: {
    type,
    token
  }
}

How can I use Sequelize to update the token field for a specific user in Postgres?

Comment: did you find a way to update json filed via sequelize?

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a question about `sequelize.js`, but I don't know much about it, so let me give a general answer about postgresql (feel free to ignore it). First, postgresql does not support modifying `json` values. `json` columns should mostly be used to store JSON data in the database and not to manipulate JSON data. If you really want to manipulate JSON data in the database then you have to use a `jsonb` column. `jsonb` can be modified with the help the `jsonb_set` function and the `||` operator. In your case, if you can run raw SQL queries, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE "user"
SET info = jsonb_set(info,'{device,token}','123')
WHERE id = 31;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user.findOne({where: {id: 31}}).then((u) => {
u.device.update(info: {type, token})

});
```

This is a user table.
with id of 31 to update the value of type and token